# Unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

There seems to be a lot of questions that have been answered but have not been accepted.

Is it worth adding a comment to these questions requesting the OP chooses an answer to accept (providing the issue has been resolved)

There is also the issue of questions that don't *have* a solution ([discussed here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/757/how-to-deal-with-how-do-i-do-x-action-in-y-webapp-where-there-is-no-way-to)) Jeff proposed a solution on that question but nothing seemed to be confirmed as the process going forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

It's totally up to the OP whether they accept or not.

There's two things against this:

1. If it's an unregistered user the chances of them coming back are slim.
2. If it's a registered user they'll see a note on their profile about accepting the answer anyway (at least for a while).

In addition you don't know whether the solution actually worked for the OP.

If you think that the answer does address the question then vote it up so it no longer appears on the "Unanswered Questions" list.